# Surjective functions and partitions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations, set-partition

Let $f: S \to T$ be a surjective function that maps the elements of each subset $S_{\alpha} \subset S$ to elements $t \in T$. The problem is to show that the collection $\{f^{-1}(\{t\}) = S_{\alpha}\}$ for each $t \in T$ partition the original set $S$.

I can show that the $\bigcup S_{\alpha} = S$.

How do I show that if $S_{\alpha} \neq S_{\beta}$, then $S_{\alpha} \cap S_{\beta} = \emptyset$?

Comment: What is $\alpha$ here?  Wouldn't it be simpler to call it $S_t$?  Then observe that if $x \in S_r \cap S_t$ then $f(x) = \ldots$

Comment: $\alpha$ is an indexing variable.

Answer (score 1):

Write $S_a = f^{-1}(t_a)$ and $S_b = f^{-1}(t_b)$. So $S_a \neq S_b$ means $t_a \neq t_b$. Now if $s \in S_a \cap S_b$ then $f(s) = t_a \neq t_b = f(s)$. So the element $s$ is mapped to two different elements, which is not allowed for a function.

Comment: Thank you! This is very clear and helpful.